# What happens during the fermentation process of the eco-enzyme?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology

[introduction about the eco-enzyme](http://www.justlifeshop.com/turn-garbage-into-enzyme/) 
I have tried to make several ones at home, no matter what I am using, lemon or pineapple peels with brown or white sugar, the final products all show the similar brown colour.
It seems to me that no matter what type of fruit peel or sugar used as the material, would all lead to a similar brown colour.

So I am curious about: 
**Why the colour of the final product is different from normal homemade fermentative fruit or vegetable?** 
*Are the microbes  involved in fermentation have some difference between the both? Is this because of the difference between enzymes that are produced by bacteria?*

I have tried to find the [appropriate and availible resource](http://www.fao.org/docrep/x0560e/x0560e07.htm) about microorganisms that may take part in the fermenting process of fruit and vegetables, but I am still not sure which one would take part in which step of the eco-enzyme. 
(In my observation, some white tiny spots and big speckles began to float on the the surface of the liquid after a week, before opening the container to release gas and make it become aerobic).

**What could be the role of fruit peels aside from being the source of microbes,if it will also produce enzymes to influence the chemical reaction?**

Is the eco-enzyme really an enzyme?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44289/questions-about-the-magical-effect-of-eco-enzyme) again instead of making the old one better?

Comment: I am sorry,perhaps it's because my limited biological knowledge limited the way I ask ,but don't you think the questions this time focus more on the microbes and the enzymes it may produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe is using yeast to convert the sugar into alcohol (ethanol). All of the proposed cleaning effect is from the dilute alcohol (and also some vinegar).  The citrus peel provides some aromatic oils. There may be low levels of some particularly hardy enzymes released from the rotting fruit and dying microbes, but it is difficult to imagine that any of those proteins have any effect on removing dirt from clothes, dishes, or surfaces. The solution is also acidic from the fermentation and the dissolved CO2 gas--just like if you used grape pulp and skins you would make a primitive wine with this recipe, and that wine would then turn into vinegar (acetic acid, HOAc).  Mixing some vinegar and alcohol would give you the same cleanser.

The enzyme concentration should be similar to the amount of active enzymes present in homemade beer or wine--would you use either of those for cleaning?